# Xamarin Forms MVVM set picker SelectedItem to a value

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm, picker

I am new to Xamarin.Forms and MVVM. I have following picker in XAML:

```
<Picker Title="Marital Status"
                        x:Name="maritalStatus"
                        Margin="10,5,10,0"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding MaritalStatusList}"
                        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Value}" 
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMaritalStatus, Mode=TwoWay}">
                </Picker>
```

This is how I setup the item source:

```
public class KeyValuePair
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public static class MaritalStatus
{
    public static List<KeyValuePair> GetMaritalStatus()
    {
        return new List<KeyValuePair>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair() {Key=1, Value="Single"},
            new KeyValuePair() {Key=1, Value="Married"},
            new KeyValuePair() {Key=1, Value="Widowed"},
            new KeyValuePair() {Key=1, Value="Divorced"},
            new KeyValuePair() {Key=1, Value="Civil Partnership"}

        };
    }
}
```

And this is how I set the property:

```
KeyValuePair selectedMaritalStatus;
    public KeyValuePair SelectedMaritalStatus
    {
        get => selectedMaritalStatus;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref selectedMaritalStatus, value);
            MaritalStatusText = selectedMaritalStatus.Value;
        }
    }

    string maritalStatusText;
    public string MaritalStatusText
    {
        get => maritalStatusText;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref maritalStatusText, value);
        }
    }
```

The above displays properly the list in the picker. My problem is that I have a form and I want to set the picker to the value that comes from a database. I have some other entries that I can successfully set from a ViewModel like so:

```
foreach (EmployeeDetails details in EmployeeDetailsService.EmployeeDetails)
        {
            Id = details.Id;
            ADEmployeeID = await new MSGraphService().GetUserIdAsync();
            FirstName = details.FirstName;
            MiddleName = details.MiddleName;
            LastName = details.LastName;
            Street = details.Address.Street;
            Block = details.Address.Block;
            City = details.Address.City;
            County = details.Address.County;
            PostCode = details.Address.PostCode;
            Telephone = details.Telephone;
            DateOfBirth = details.DateOfBirth != null ? DateTime.Parse(details.DateOfBirth) : DateTime.Now.Date;
            CountryOfBirth = details.CountryOfBirth;
            SelectedMaritalStatus.Value = details.MaritalStatus;
            //MaritalStatusText = details.MaritalStatus;
            PassportIssuingCountry = details.PassportIssuingCountry;
            PassportNumber = details.PassportNumber;
            PassportExpiryDate = details.PassportExpiryDate != null ? DateTime.Parse(details.PassportExpiryDate) : DateTime.Now.Date;
            BankName = details.BankName;
            BankAddress = details.BankAddress;
            BankSortCode = details.BankSortCode;
            NationalInsuranceNumber = details.NationalInsuranceNumber;
            //    //! Need to add P45
        }
```

Marital Status picker is the only one that I cannot set, everything else works.

*** **UPDATE** ***

This is my SetProperty:

```
protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value,
        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "",
        Action onChanged = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value)) { return false; }

        backingStore = value;
        onChanged?.Invoke();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed == null) { return; }

        changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you need to lookup the value from the db in `MaritalStatusList` and set `SelectedMaritalStatus` to that value.  `SelectedItem` has to be one of the values in `ItemsSource`

Comment: Hi Jason. Thank you for your quick reply. I changed my code to this: SelectedMaritalStatus = new KeyValuePair() { Key = 1, Value = details.MaritalStatus }; Now I can see that the set is called and the value is set correctly but the UI does not update with the new value. Any idea why?

Comment: because you are setting `SelectedMaritalStatus` to a **new instance**, not one of the instances that already exists in `MaritalStatusList`

Comment: Hi Jason. Could you possibly give me an example based on the code structure that I have? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SelectedMaritalStatus` has to be one of the objects in `MaritalStatusList`

```
SelectedMaritalStatus = MaritalStatusList[0];
```

or

```
SelectedMaritalStatus = MaritalStatusList.First(x => x.ID == "some value from your db");
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jason. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set defalut value of the Xamarin `Picker`. You just set the `selectedIndex`(the first number of index is 0) of your picker in `yourpage.xaml.cs` just as follows:

```
maritalStatus.SelectedIndex=1;
```

The whole code is:

```
   public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        maritalStatus.SelectedIndex = 1;
    }

// other code
}
```

**Note:**

I suggest you rename your Picker to better indentify your Picker(e.g. `mStatusPicker`)